# What is the correct way to create a custom action using REST API in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, custom-actions, json, spfx-extensions

I'm trying to use **Microsoft Flow** and the **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action to deploy an SPFx application customizer to a modern team site.

I'm able to use the /_api/Site/UserCustomActions endpoint to list existing custom actions but keep getting errors when I try to create new using REST

Site address: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/a-modern-team-site

Method: POST

Uri: /_api/Site/UserCustomActions

Headers:

- Accept application/json; odata=verbose
- Content-Type application/json; odata=verbose

Body:

```
{
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.UserCustomAction' },
    "Location":"ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer",
    "Rights":"ManageWeb",
    "Title":"EnableTeamsApplicationCustomizer",
    "Name":"EnableTeamsApplicationCustomizer",  
    "ClientSideComponentId":"fa80f680-bda9-4c15-a8fe-4e86be0bf593", 
    "ClientSideComponentProperties":"{\"autoCreate\":\"true\"}"
}
```

Here's the error I keep getting. I have tried various encoding of the client side properties, omitted it, but no results. I have tried different variations of the http headers, both with odata=verbose and odata=nometadata. I keep getting the same error, but can't find anything explaining the error.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.\r\nclientRequestId: 43c303e3-4722-4b5e-a5b5-5fbcc686ec50\r\nserviceRequestId: 1b1e6c9e-a0a1-5000-f082-74dd369cc50f",
  "source": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/a-modern-team-site/_api/Site/UserCustomActions",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
  ]
```

}

Comment: Thanks for posting though, saved me a lot of trial and error (the UserCustomActionCollection does not support the PUT method and I was wondering how to create actions then, now that I knew a simple POST works for you I tried it for myself and indeed it does :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong. The "Rights" property doesn't take a string like "ManageWeb" but is an object with High and Low properties.

I had to either remove the property or define the High and Low permission mask bits.